# start -x lists some commands. How can you trace back to the application issuing the command

Tags: linux

I did a last -x

```
pi       pts/0        fe80::ee35:7d68: Fri Feb  9 07:56   still logged in
runlevel (to lvl 3)   5.4.51-v7+       Thu Feb  8 20:50   still running
pi       tty1                          Thu Feb  8 20:41    gone - no logout
reboot   system boot  5.4.51-v7+       Thu Jan  1 00:00   still running
runlevel (to lvl 3)   5.4.51-v7+       Thu Feb  8 15:00 - 20:50  (05:49)
```

I have an unexpected reboot as seen, but how can I trace back to the process, app or script issuing the reboot command? I know it was not caused by a manual command?

Comment: What do you get with `journalctl | grep reboot`?

Comment: Nothing actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an unexpected reboot as seen, but how can I trace back to the process, app or script issuing the reboot command?

You can't.

For that matter, that looks like the kind of reboot that happened *not* because of a command, but more likely because of **external** causes such as a crash or a power outage or a physical reset.